# eth0 is gone. Ubuntu 22.04 only sees lo

Tags: networking, 22.04, network-manager, ethernet

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 with NetworkManager. eth0 has disappeared, and the internet does not work. The `ip a` command only shows lo. There is no `/etc/network/interfaces` file at all. The `ls /sys/class/net` command only shows lo. The `lshw  | grep Eth` command shows the Realtek network card.

Comment: Watch your system startup and discover (or not) the hardware with the terminal command `sudo journalctl  -b 0`.